# Disappearing line object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a strange problem, which can be a three.js bug, but it also can be my curve hands.
I have a scene with some meshes (in example below I used several transparent cubes and small spheres) and one **line object** (can be Line or LineSegments - doesn't matter) based on **buffer geometry**. While I rotating the camera line object sometimes disappears form view like it's covered by another object. It seems it also disappears if I cannot see the start point (if rotate camera to a degree where start point is offscreen, even without additional meshes) of the line while 90% of the line object should be in view.
**The question is**: Why does the line disappear and how should I prevent such its behavior?
This is how it looks on screencast:
http://screencast.com/t/HLC99OMmDdK

And this is an example of the problem:
[http://jsfiddle.net/exiara/sa4bxhc3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mgugj9kk/1/) 
You should be able to see how line disappears when camera rotates.

The code of jsfiddle example:

```
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer, dummy, projector,
            stats, fps = 30, fpsTimeout = 1000 / fps,
            linesGeometry,globalLine;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
            renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFeF, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xFFFFeF, 100, 2500 );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 50000 );
            camera.position.set(-450, 300, 650);
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener('change', render );

            // ------------ MAIN PART START ------------ //

            var lines = 1000;
            linesGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
            var positions = new Float32Array( lines * 6 );
            for ( var i = 0, j, ll = lines; i < ll; i++ ) {
                j=i*6;
                positions[j]   = Math.random()*100;
                positions[j+1] = Math.random()*100;
                positions[j+2] = Math.random()*100;
                positions[j+3] = Math.random()*100;
                positions[j+4] = Math.random()*100;
                positions[j+5] = Math.random()*100;
            }
            linesGeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
            globalLine = new THREE.Line( linesGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0x000000,
                transparent: true,
                opacity: 0.8
            } ));
            scene.add( globalLine );

            // ------------ MAIN PART END ------------ //

            // add cubes
            var step = 400;
            var gridSize = 4;
            var offset = step*gridSize/2;

            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(step, step, step);
            var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xFF0000, ambient: 0xCCCCCC, transparent: true, opacity: 0 });

            var testCube, edge;
            for (var x = -offset; x <= offset; x+=step) {
                for (var y = -offset; y <= offset; y+=step) {
                    for (var z = -offset; z <= offset; z+=step) {
                        testCube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry,cubeMaterial);
                        testCube.position.set(x, y, z);
                        edge = new THREE.EdgesHelper( testCube, 0x000000 );
                        scene.add(testCube);
                        scene.add(edge);
                    }
                }
            }

            // spheres
            var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10,32,16),
                sphere;
            var spheres = [
                [0xff0000, 0,    0,    0   ], // red
                [0x0000ff, 200,  0,    0   ], // blue
                [0x00FF00, -200, 0,    0   ], // green
                [0xFF00ff, 0,    200,  0   ], // magenta
                [0x00ffff, 0,    -200, 0   ], // aqua
                [0xFFff00, 0,    0,    200 ], // lime
                [0x000000, 0,    0,    -200]  // black
            ];
            for (var i = 0, sl = spheres.length; i <sl; i++) {
                sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: spheres[i][0]}));
                sphere.position.set(spheres[i][1], spheres[i][2], spheres[i][3]);
                scene.add(sphere);
            }

            /* Stats */
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            /* window observers */
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            window.addEventListener( 'load', render, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function degInRad(deg) {
            return deg * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        function animate()
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }, fpsTimeout );
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            camera.lookAt(camera.target);
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            stats.update();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing multiple levels of opacity on top of each other and webgl needs to sort them. So the short answer is to add `depthTest: false` to your cube material.

```
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xFF0000, ambient: 0xCCCCCC, transparent: true, opacity: 0, depthTest: false });
```

But I would like to mention that what you are doing is inefficient. You should not be drawing a grid that way. Use lines instead.

Comment: `depthTest: false` use has no effect. Cubes are just an example when an issue can be easily reproduced. It's inefficient but displays the problem. You can see spheres are always displayed and lines flickering. And I have a similar problem in a live project with lines disappearing even without transparent cubes. I just rotate camera so line stars position (0,0,0) in my case is just out of the screen. Then all of the line disappears while it's only a small part of the line is outside of view.

Comment: Sorry but when I add `depthTest: false` the problem goes away (on my machine).

Comment: Hm, I've lied. It's indeed solved the problem with transparent cubes. But not with off-screen start point. Anyway for a certain example your answer is correct. Thanks.